# Can we use callbacks in the mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to insert one document into `collection1` and after successfully inserting the document, I want to insert another document into `collection2`. One of the fields for the document in `collection2` will be the `_id` of the document just inserted into `collection1`.

I am using a callback:

```
db.collection1.insert(<document>,function(err,doc)){
     db.collection2.insert({collection1_id: doc[0]._id, <field>:<value>})
```

However, it seems that callback is not available without `Node.js`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Whay do you mean by without node.js? In Mongo shell?

Comment: @estus, yes, in mongo shell or just in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks are part of the Node.js async API and are not supported in the `mongo` shell (as at MongoDB 4.0). However, you can always write the equivalent without callbacks.

The `mongo` shell's [`insertOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) method will return an `insertedId` field with the `_id` value of the inserted document, so you can either save or reference this value.

For example:

```
db.collection2.insertOne({
    collection1_id: db.collection1.insertOne({}).insertedId,
    field: 'value'
})
```

Comment: how can one practically use this value ?

Comment: @user1767316 There's an example in the answer referencing the `insertedId` for a new document: `db.collection1.insertOne({}).insertedId`. If that isn't what you're looking for, I'd suggest asking a new question with relevant details.